# Check if variable is empty in PhpStorm file template

Tags: phpstorm, apache-velocity

I'm trying to follow Zend coding standard for comments blocks for functions and I've stuck during `PHP Function Doc Comment`customization.

This is my current code look

```
/**
${PARAM_DOC}
#if(${PARAM_DOC})
 *
#end
 * @return ${TYPE_HINT}
${THROWS_DOC}
*/
```

The assumption for this is that it should add an asterisk only if `${PARAM_DOC}` is not nullable, but this code doesn't work. It always adds an asterisk. The documentation of PhpStorm Variables doesn't contain any useful informations for my problem so I hope that somebody here can help me.

My PhpStorm version is 2019.3 EAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the build-in PhpStorm for `${PARAM_DOC}` description says

> Parameters' doc comment.
>   Generated as a number of lines '* @param type name". If there are no parameters, evaluates to an empty content.

And Apache Velocity docs says

> When VTL references a variable, such as $foo, the variable can get its value from either a set directive in the template, or from the Java code.

After that I understood that I'm making one important mistake. PhpStorm is based on Java and an empty *String* cant be automatically casted to *Boolean* beacuse `${PARAM_DOC}` is just a *Java String*.

So solution for that turned out to be

```
#if (${PARAM_DOC} != "")
 *
#end
```

Obvious but not quiet.